# Backbone inside a static path? Anyway to window.location + '#'?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

So I have a problem, my demo app that I want to showcase on my server is on a static path `example.com/projects` all the `a` tags have `href="/#mail"` etc, when that is clicked it obviously just links to `example.com/#mail` instead of `example.com/projects/#mail`.

The solution would be to change all `a` tags to add `/projects/#mail` but is there a better solution, if I want to push from dev to production I want a `git-commit` + `git-push` and that be it.

Comment: Are you using Backbone routes in a single page app or loading separate pages? If the former, Backbone pretty much does what you want "out of the box." If the latter, it's not really a Backbone issue. You'd have to handle it on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the current directory: `href="./#mail"`

Comment: Oh really, I usually do `./` I didnt really know that would work. Okay thanks man. Let me try it out